CMake Error: Could not find toolchain file: ... Путь дублируется
В CMake не разбираюсь. Пытаюсь собрать MEGA SDK для использования в своём Android-приложении.
Я установил vcpkg в ~ выполнил vcpkg integrate install.
Когда я выполняю:
cmake -DVCPKG_ROOT=~/vcpkg -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/mrcookie/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -S sdk -B build_dir

чтобы настроить сборку (как сказано в README репозитория MEGA SDK, ссылка выше, аргумент CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE добавил по указанию вывода vcpkg integrate install, но даже если его убрать, проблема не исчезает), я вижу следующий вывод:
-- [SDKlib] is a top-level project. Install target is enabled by default.
-- Examples and tests will be enabled by default.
-- Using VCPKG dependencies. VCPKG base path: /home/mrcookie/vcpkg and tripplet x64-linux-mega
-- Overlay for VCPKG ports: /run/media/mrcookie/MyFiles/MyApps/HometaskViewer2/megasdk/src/main/cpp/sdk/cmake/vcpkg_overlay_ports
-- Overlay for VCPKG triplets: /run/media/mrcookie/MyFiles/MyApps/HometaskViewer2/megasdk/src/main/cpp/sdk/cmake/vcpkg_overlay_triplets
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:176 (message):
  Could not find toolchain file:
  /home/mrcookie/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake;/home/mrcookie/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:92 (project)


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!


Почему-то путь к файлу тулчейна дублируется, и CMake не может его найти:
Could not find toolchain file:
  /home/mrcookie/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake;/home/mrcookie/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake

Пробовал в CMakeLists.txt библиотеки MEGA SDK добавлять строчку:
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/home/mrcookie/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE STRING "VCPKG")

Но это не помогло.

"как сказано в README репозитория MEGA SDK" - аргумент CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE там нигде не упоминается, это какая-то самодеятельность

@user7860670 да, забыл сказать, этот аргумент говорит ставить вывод vcpkg integrate install. Но даже если его убрать, проблема не исчезает

¿Зачем вы выполняли vcpkg integrate install? В README о нем тоже не упоминается

Убери параметр VCPKG_ROOT, и просто оставь --toolchain=/home/mrcookie/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake, а так проблема в том что у тебя путь дублируется

@user7860670 а иначе его cmake вообще не видит, пытается заново устновить, но у него не выходит, и выбрасывается ошибка

@evo выполнил cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug --toolchain=/home/mrcookie/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -S sdk -B build_dir  но путь всё ещё дублируется

Сбрось кэш, удали папку с кэшем

@evo удалил build_dir, теперь при запуске той же команды он не видит vcpkg, пытается установить, но бросает ошибку

Какую ошибку? Добавь

Это сам проект "дублирует" значение переменной CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE: cmake/modules/vcpkg_management.cmake: set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} ${VCPKG_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}). Этот код концептуально некорректен, так как значение переменной должно быть единой строкой, а не списком. Можете попробовать действительно не устанавливать переменную CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE в командной строке: тогда этой переменной будет назначено в коде только одно значение, а не два.
